# Using Scrolling Activity inside Navigation Activity

Tags: android, material-design

my primary goal is to have a navigation drawer with a Scrolling Activity while implementing material design so it would look something like a combination of these two:

[Navigation Drawer Sample Image (Credits to Google)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2elU2.png)

[Scrolling Activity Sample Image (Credits to Google)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl1f8.jpg)

As of right now I am doing this by associating a Navigation Drawer Layout's xml to my main activity and then including a Scrolling Layout's xml inside of Navigation Drawer Layout's content xml.

It's working after implementing many small changes in xmls of both the layouts but I don't feel like it's the optimal way to do so as it results in  using more than 7 xmls at once for only one activity.

Does anybody know of a better way to do so?

Comment: You could do it all in one layout, if you want. However you want to modularize your code and layouts is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Molecularity is not bugging me, after all it's a good thing to have separate modules for separate sections of the code. My concern is that having so many xmls processed at once might slow down the app.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it unless you have some reason to suspect that it's slowing your app. Seven isn't that many, and layouts are pre-compiled in your app specifically to make inflation fast and efficient. Now, if you have hundreds of `View`s in those layouts, then that might cause some lag, but just having several separate layouts isn't necessarily a problem, in and of itself.

Comment: Thank you for info and clarification. I suspected layouts because the app was getting slow, I could see the frame drops even while pulling down the notification tray. But I've found the real culprit, it isn't the layouts but when I place some rendered images (.png) in the content it significantly slows down the app for some reason. After removing the images I was able to get it working smooth again. Which is still a problem as I need those images. Guess I'll have to search/post a separate question on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include scrolling layout into navigation layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include layout="@layout/activity_scrolling"/>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```